# Como gerenciar um projeto com diversas variações?

Tags: gerenciamento-de-projetos, branch

Como vocês gerenciam o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação que é replicada para diversos clientes?

**Meu cenário:**

Uma aplicação *web* e 2 *apps* (1 para iOS e 1 para Android). Para cada cliente a base (master) é reutilizada e são adicionados recursos específicos que suprem suas necessidades. Quando um recurso é de interesse comum, o mesmo é adicionado na base para que os demais consigam usufruir do mesmo.

**Ao chegar um novo cliente:**

Cria-se um novo *branch* para as 3 aplicações, aplica-se sua identidade e realiza a implantação.

**Minha dúvida:**

Como vocês consideram a melhor forma de gerenciar este tipo de projeto?

- Através de *branches* (como vem sendo feito)
- Um novo projeto para cada novo cliente
- Outras sugestões

**Lembrando ainda:**

O ambiente que utilizo está com integração contínua (CI) com o Jenkins. Logo, como gerenciar o build para cada um dos clientes? Para cada cliente um build? Um build para todas as variações (todos os clientes)?

Agradeço a quem puder contribuir para o esclarecimento desta dúvida.

Answer (score 2):

Eu faria um repositório central aonde clonaria o esqueleto da aplicação e cada módulo seria criado separadamente da aplicação para ser instalado através de gerenciadores de pacote, assim iria facilitar o update de cada módulo e já instalar tudo quando eu clonar o repositório central (o esqueleto).

Um repositório para cada projeto em vez de branches também vai facilitar, eu uso branches para novos recursos em vez de ramificações definitivas do projeto principal, mesmo que você precise criar um processo de build no Jenkins para cada novo cliente que tiver (claro que cada caso é um caso, mas achei mais prático fazer o build com Git puro e automatizar as tarefas com shell script, mas o que é prático pra mim pode não ser para você e vice-versa).